# Can't change text entry language (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: language-support, ibus, japanese, chinese

I normally switch between Chinese, Japanese, English an Spanish for typing. I installed the languages at language support, set ibus as the input method, installed input methods for Chinese (sougou, bopomofo, pinyin and sunpinyin) and restarted the computer. 
When I select another language other than English, the keyboard is still in English; for Spanish I can't type the ñ, and for Japanese and Chinese the text won't change into characters.
Then I tried setting fcitx as the input method, but none of the languages are displayed if I want to switch between languages, only English.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I do not know for other languages but for Spanish (French and other languages with accents or annotations on letters) you can add `English (US, alternative international)`.  With this you can just first press the key for the accent/annotation and right after the letter.  For instance ~ and then n give you ñ.

Comment: I think you need provide more details, such as: Exactly which packages did you install, how do you switch input language, does the input source menu list all the languages you want to use. Also, please read [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: You need some other packages ibus-anthy or fcitx-mozc for Japanese. After that, you need some configurations for each input method and engines, open ibus/fcitx setting, then Anthy/Mozc setting to type Japanese characters, so does Chinese. Some combinations stopped developing, e.g. ibus-mozc. They are no longer useful for new Ubuntu releases.